# Google API RS256 Key Signing

Tags: google-api, erlang, elixir, public-key-encryption

I wanted to implement [Google's OAuth 2.0 Sever to Server](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) process in Erlang/Elixir, but am having a bit of difficutly.

Primarily, I can't seem to find the public key that Google is using to verify my signature (at least this is what I think the problem is.

I've downloaded the JSON file that google provides which includes a "private_key" as well as a URL where I can find the "client_x509_certs". When I go to that link I even see an x509 certificate that has an identifier that corresponds to my private key. So how come I can't verify my signatures?

I mean first off, in order to make erlang happy I had to convert the private key to the RSA format using this command:

`openssl rsa -in key.pem -out rsa.key`

I was then able to sign things using Erlang's [public_key.sign](http://erlang.org/doc/man/public_key.html#sign-3).

```
{ :ok, key } = File.read("./private_key")
[ key | _ ] = :public_key.pem_decode(key)
key = :public_key.pem_entry_decode(key)
sig = :public_key.sign("halloween", :sha256, key)
```

However, after extracting the RSA public key from the x509 certificates provided in the UR; I can't verify any of my signatures.

```
:public_key.verify("halloween", :sha256, sig, public_key)
```

Am I not getting my public key from the right place?